# Jquery ui autocomplete autoFocus on android device

Tags: android, google-chrome, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using [Jquery ui autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

I am using the [autoFocus](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-autoFocus) option so that as soon as the autocomplete list is shown, the first option is automatically selected.

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/32Bck/2718/) is a fiddle. The autocomplete code is:

```
$(".ac").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        autoFocus: true
    });
```

However, if this is tested on a chrome browser on android, then for any non-last form input, the item isn't selected.

Upon inspection, I noticed that the "enter" (button on bottom right of keyboard) button on an android device for any non-last input element in a form is "Next" while the "enter" button for the last input element of the form is "Go".

The issue I described only occurs when the "enter" button is "Next" (ie: any non-last input element).

Are there any suggestions for how I might fix this issue? That is, how can I have the "enter" key select the auto focused element on an android Chrome browser?

Thanks

Comment: I do not suspect you will be able to change the keyboard button as it is not an element of Chrome, but of the operating system. The 'Next' function allows the user to move to the next element in the form, similar to Tab. The 'Go' function allows the form to be submitted, similar to Enter. So you cannot "fix" the issue, it's by design. You can look for a specific event, and then trigger `select` when that event is called. This will ensure that Next and Go can be useful for you.

Comment: Also, from here https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/keyboardevent-keys-codes I found this: https://w3c.github.io/uievents/tools/key-event-viewer.html Helpful in testing.

Comment: Looking at the test results, 'Go', passes the 'enter' key press. 'Next' does not event seem to send an event. It's really weird. Will keep digging.

Comment: Based on this extended thread, https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=118639 , the issue comes down to the virtual keyboard. This is complicated since users can install alternate versions of keyboards to use that may or may not return the proper key codes and may also function in different manners. This does not yet even touch on alternate non-western keyboards. I strongly suggest avoid using these keys if possible.

Comment: @Twisty thanks. Do you have a suggestion for how to fix this? The basis of the problem is that if this "next" (enter) button is pushed, the auto selected autocomplete result is not selected.

Comment: It is not exactly something that you can "fix". You could try alternate keyboards on Android. But if this website is for more people than yourself, you have no way to control the keyboard or even the browser they are using. So the 'Next' button may not even appear for some. Maybe they have Chrome installed on an older Android version that does not offer 'Next' or 'Go' but only 'Done'.

Comment: @Twisty I address this issue by turning off `autoFocus` if Chrome browser and android device is detected. I am still looking for a workaround for this though to have `autoFocus` work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to get/set the focused item through events callbacks.

See this example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var availableTags = [
    "ActionScript",
    "AppleScript",
    "Asp",
    "BASIC",
    "C",
    "C++",
    "Clojure",
    "COBOL",
    "ColdFusion",
    "Erlang",
    "Fortran",
    "Groovy",
    "Haskell",
    "Java",
    "JavaScript",
    "Lisp",
    "Perl",
    "PHP",
    "Python",
    "Ruby",
    "Scala",
    "Scheme"
  ];
  // Add variable to hold focued item value
  let focusedItem = '';
  
  $(".ac").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    autoFocus: true,
    
    
    focus: function(event, ui) {
    // on focus set the focued item value to the variable
      focusedItem = ui.item.value;
      return true;
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {
      // user moved away from input, if variable is not null set it to input
      if (focusedItem != '') 
        jQuery(this).val(focusedItem);
      

      return true;
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form>

  <input type="text" class="ac" />
  <input type="text" class="ac">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can capture enter button on keypress.

```js
$('input').on('keydown', function(e){
    if(e.which === 9) {
        //your code here
    }
});
```

then set focus manually to your autocomplete.

Comment: This is not the keycode that is fired when "Next" is pushed. You can test this and see that javascript returns `0` for the keycode.

Comment: i have tested in android device and it is returning `13` as keycode.

Comment: Maybe the `enter` button does, but not "next", try on an element that is not the last one in the form.